# Finding the contentLength for response from Salesforce Connector Mule 4

Tags: mule, mule4, mule-connector

I have been working on a mule app(4.4.0) where it calls a salesforce query connector and converts the response from SF connector to CSV and then upload the CSV to AWS s3 via create an object connector.

I am getting errors as: "com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Data read has a different length than the expected"

My code config looks like below:-

```
        <salesforce:query doc:name="sobject from salesforce" doc:id="58660352-f117-47e3-91cf-587f5000d591" config-ref="salesforceConfig" >
                    <salesforce:salesforce-query >#[vars.query]</salesforce:salesforce-query>
                    </salesforce:query>
                    
    <ee:transform doc:name="convert to csv" doc:id="ed22a2df-82a6-4162-9c3d-eab29dc92a4f">
                    <ee:message>
                        <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
        output application/csv quoteHeader=true, quoteValues=true
        ---
        payload]]></ee:set-payload>
                    </ee:message>
                </ee:transform>

<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="62f61426-f0df-4640-bb27-4a980a4f26fa" >
            <ee:message >
            </ee:message>
            <ee:variables >
                <ee:set-variable variableName="contentLength" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
sizeOf(write(payload, "application/java"))]]></ee:set-variable>
            </ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
    
    <s3:create-object doc:name="Create object" doc:id="136d5816-846c-4e52-acb6-0caeacb25dba" config-ref="Amazon_S3_Configuration" bucketName="#[vars.s3BucketName]" key='#[(if(!isEmpty(vars.s3WriteKey)) vars.s3WriteKey ++ "/" else "") ++ vars.fileNameOnS3]' contentLength="#[vars.contentLength]"/>
```

Its creating exception as like below:-

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: More data read than expected: dataLength=1048; expectedLength=7; includeSkipped=false; in.getClass()=class com.amazonaws.internal.ReleasableInputStream; markedSupported=false; marked=0; resetSinceLastMarked=false; markCount=0; resetCount=0
```

I could see this error is due to contentLength which i calculate based on payload size could not match . I tried various options like sizeOf(payload) , sizeOf(write(payload)) etc . all same error.

Any helps really appreciated. Many Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short Version:

Opt for either of the two:

1. Do not pass the `contentLength` Param unless it is required for some usecase, as it is handled automatically.
2. If, for some reason, you have to pass the `contentLength` you should write your payload as String using `write(payload, 'application/csv', {quoteHeader: true, quoteValues: true})`. Then you can get the size of the payload using either `sizeOf(payload)` or the Content Length Metadata Selector `payload.^contentLength` (before using later, read the 3rd point in
   the long version)

#### Long Version:

While calculating the size of your CSV you are writing the payload as `application/java`, which will write your CSV into a Java `ArrayList` and then calculate the size of that string.

Now you would think that changing `application/java` to `application/csv` will solve the problem, but no. If you check the documentation of [write](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-write) function, you will find that it accepts the third parameter called `writerProperties`, which in your case, is `{quoteHeader: true, quoteValues: true}` *(These are the ones that you are using while creating the payload)*. Because these properties are not the default ones, you will get a different output from the `write` function from that of your payload **if you do not specify these properties in your write function**.

*What you should do?*

1. I would first see if I really need to pass the contentLength myself? As far as I know it will be handled automatically.
2. If you really need to pass the `contentLength`, you should first write your payload as in the desired format after you transform it as CSV, something like the following

```js
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
write (payload, "application/csv", {quoteHeader: true, quoteValues: true})
```

Then you can use the sizeOf(payload). You should not be modifying the payload while calculating the size, because, that modification could change the length, as you just experienced.

3. **Requires Testing:**. Since you are using the application/csv content type you can get the `contentLength` directly using the [Content Length Metadata Selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-cookbook-extract-data#caret_contentlength). i.e. `payload.^contentLength`. However, I am saying that it requires testing, because this metadata selector sometimes returns null, for example, when the payload output type is `application/java`. I am 99% sure with csv you will always get the content type metadata, but not 100% as I do not know why it is not populated sometimes in other MIME Types. If you choose to use this, your s3 connector will look like this

```xml
<s3:create-object doc:name="Create object"
                  doc:id="136d5816-846c-4e52-acb6-0caeacb25dba"
                  config-ref="Amazon_S3_Configuration"
                  bucketName="#[vars.s3BucketName]"
                  key='#[(if(!isEmpty(vars.s3WriteKey)) vars.s3WriteKey ++ "/" else "") ++ vars.fileNameOnS3]'
                  contentLength="#[payload.^contentLength]"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and effort to provide a detailed answer. The first one works and yet to test the second one.